# ZF2 + Doctrine2: Server has gone away - how to jog an old connection?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm wondering if anyone quickly knows what functions to call on the Entity Repository to jog its reconnection if it is dead.  I am running some jobs that can take a length of time that exceeds wait_timeout through a ZF2 CLI route, and unfortunately, the ER's connection dies by the time it needs to get used (when the job is done).

Need:

```
// do the long job

$sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
$mapper = $sl->get( 'doctrine_object_mapper' );
if( !$mapper->getRepository()->isAlive() ) // something like so
    $mapper->getRepository()->wakeTheHellUp();
```

Aren't those proper method names! ;)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [fairly common problem](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-275) with long running processes and connections.

The solution is to retrieve the ORM's [DBAL connection](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php) and re-create it if the connection was lost (ensuring it didn't die during a transaction). This is obviously annoying, but it's the only way of doing it right now:

```php
// note - you need a ServiceManager here, not just a generic service locator
$entityMAnager = $serviceManager->get('entity_manager');
$connection    = $entityManager->getConnection();

try {
    // dummy query
    $connection->query('SELECT 1');
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
    if ($connection->getTransactionIsolation()) {
        // failed in the middle of a transaction - this is serious!
        throw $e;
    }

    // force instantiation of a new entity manager
    $entityManager = $serviceManager->create('entity_manager');
}

$this->doFoo($entityManager);
```

Comment: Thanks Ocramius.  I guess I'll have to refactor to use a factory for the long-running service in order to get the SM into there.  Right now , I had the SL being dropped in through implementing ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and declaring it as an Invokable in module.config.php.  I'll give it a shot and post back.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Saeven the main service manager is actually a service locator. While you *could* use it directly right now, I suggest to have correct type hinting to avoid problems in future :)

Comment: As follow-up to this problem, which I solved only yesterday - here's a small write up that might help.  Source files, explanation, and why Ocramius' post was a stepping stone.  To his credit, he actually steered me in the final direction through IRC.  http://circlical.com/blog/2013/9/12/mysql-server-has-gone-away-atop-doctrine2-and-zend-framework-2

Comment: As an update on this, the DBAL connection now supports `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection#ping()`, which allows for checking connection status without using platform specific SQL.