# zf2. How to deal with timeouts for mysql connections in a looped cli script?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

There is an infinite loop `do{ doSomethingIfNeeded(); } while(true)` running in a cli php script with `doSomethingIfNeeded()` performing some DB operations if its condition is satisfied.

The problem is that waiting can be even 12 hours long, so I got **General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away** with `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::executeQuery` at the end of exception trace.

How should I deal with the problem concerned? Should I configure mysql to handle long waiting cli scripts normally without affecting common php-fpm scripts?

I have a couple of ideas.

1. Add ping (just executing `select 1`  every minute) to the cli script
2. Set **wait_timeout** to 86400.
3. Anything else?

**Upd:** found a solution for zf2+doctrine2 - http://circlical.com/blog/2013/9/12/mysql-server-has-gone-away-atop-doctrine2-and-zend-framework-2

**Upd2:** Found a solution using zf2 `ServiceManager` - [ZF2 + Doctrine2: Server has gone away - how to jog an old connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362070/zf2-doctrine2-server-has-gone-away-how-to-jog-an-old-connection)

Comment: Create the connection when needed ?

Comment: Leaving the connection open can have unintended side effects, especially if you're relying on connection closure to commit a transaction.

Comment: @frz3993 and drop it after every single execution?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply disconnect when you are not using then reconnect to MySQL if it matches your condition.  I doubt that would have a negative hit on performance. E.g.,

```
while (true) {
    if ($condition) {
        $db->connect();
        /* your code goes here */
        $db->disconnect();
    }
}
```

If for some reason you want to keep it open, you could have it disconnect from MySQL after 1 minute of inactivity, e.g.

```
$lastActiveTime = 0;
$isConnected = false;
while (true) {
    if ((time()-$lastActiveTime)>60) {
        $isConnected = false;
        $db->disconnect();
    }
    if ($condition) {
        if (!$isConnected) $db->connect();
        $lastActiveTime = time();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific zf2+doctrine solution? It connects automatically when execution starts.

Comment: Does this help? someone else had the same problem http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/dealing-with-mysql-gone-away-in-zend-framework

Comment: The key thing is that I hardly can realize your answer in zf2-style. But it is new to me not to deal with exceptions but to control timeout manually.

Comment: Do you have access to the service locator in your code? ` $this->db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');` ?  check this http://xpo6.com/zf2-sharing-db-connection/

Comment: I think it would help if you post the code that runs the queries so we can get more info on how you are querying the database.

Comment: Thanks for help. Found specific solution for zf2+doctrine2, so I have updated the post.